# Java URLClassLoader ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, jar, classloader

I have to write a `.jar class loader` in an assignment for school. I've found this code in another question but can't figure out why it wont work.

I've set the path to be an absolute path to make sure it references to the right file.

```
System.out.println("Loading game: " + name);
URL url = new URL("file:///home/<name>/Documents/School/thema2.3/batavus/batavus/gamemodules/TicTacToe.jar");
ClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{url});
Class<?> clazz = loader.loadClass("spatboard.game." + name);
Class<? extends Game> boardClass = clazz.asSubclass(Game.class);
Constructor<? extends Game> ctor = boardClass.getConstructor();
return ctor.newInstance(board);
```

The error I get is:

```
Loading game: TicTacToe
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: spatboard.game.TicTacToe
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at spatbord.loader.GameLoader.loadModule(GameLoader.java:29)
at spatbord.model.Board.<init>(Board.java:51)
at spatbord.controller.GameController.onMatchStarted(GameController.java:157)
at spatbord.connection.Server.matchStarted(Server.java:428)
at spatbord.connection.Server.handleInput(Server.java:346)
at spatbord.connection.Server.run(Server.java:145)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The package declaration in the `TicTacToe` is `package spatbord.game;`

The contents of the jar are:

```
spatbord
 -> game
  -> TicTacToe.class
```

What am I not seeing here?

Comment: jar tf command to view your jar contents and update your question with the result

Comment: `spatboard.game.TicTacToe` there is a typo somewhere..

Comment: change ` loader.loadClass("spatboard.game." + name);` to ` loader.loadClass("spatbord.game." + name);`

Answer (score 5):

Look at this stacktrace:

```
Loading game: TicTacToe
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: spatboard.game.TicTacToe
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at spatbord.loader.GameLoader.loadModule(GameLoader.java:29)
at spatbord.model.Board.<init>(Board.java:51)
at spatbord.controller.GameController.onMatchStarted(GameController.java:157)
at spatbord.connection.Server.matchStarted(Server.java:428)
at spatbord.connection.Server.handleInput(Server.java:346)
at spatbord.connection.Server.run(Server.java:145)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

and the contents:

```
spatbord
 -> game
  -> TicTacToe.class
```

Specifically at this line:

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: spatboard.game.TicTacToe`

the JRE is expecting `spatbord.game.TicTacToe`, so this means you mispelled your package `spatboard` `spatbord`.

Answer (score -1):

Please Use URLClassLoader instead of ClassLoader in 3rd line of code.

```
URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{url});
```

Let me know this worked or not.